# How to load class at every page load in advanced app

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to have class in which I would put all my methods that should run everytime someone loads a page, lets call it InitRoutines.

In yii2 basic app I would do something like this. I would add class to compontents config file, and add it to bootstrap, simple as that.

But I can not figure out how to do it in advanced app, preferable in common/config

**config.php**

```
$config = [
    // ..
    'components' => [
        'InitRoutines' => [
            'class' => 'app\commands\InitRoutines',
        ],
    ],
];

$config['bootstrap'][] = 'InitRoutines';
```

And in InitRoutines I have init class which run everything I need at page load.

**InitRoutines.php**

```
namespace app\commands;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Component;
use app\commands\AppHelper;
use app\commands\Access;

class InitRoutines extends Component
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        Access::checkForMaintenance();
        Yii::$app->language = AppHelper::getUserLanguageCode();
    }
}
```

How can I accomplish same in advanced app ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution, I dont know if it is correct way but it seem to be working.

**config.php**

```
return [
    // ...
    'components' => [
        'InitRoutines' => [
            'class' => 'common\commands\InitRoutines',
        ],
    ],
    'bootstrap' => [
        'log',
        'common\commands\InitRoutines'
    ],
];
```

Comment: Consider creating a custom `Controller` class inherited from `yii\web\Controller`. Then you can put your logic into the `beforeAction` method.

Comment: @Beowulfenator if this solution works, it's much better than extending `yii\web\Controller` because it saves you the work of changing all the generated Controllers' declaration

Comment: @deacs yes that was main purpose of this solution