# Yii Framework action before every controller

Tags: php, yii, controller

is there any "main" controller which fires before every other controller from folder "controllers"? I have a project where every user has his different site language, so I want to check the setting first and then set the language using:

```
Yii::$app->language='en-EN';
```

Right now I do this in every controller I have, but I guess it should be an easier option.

Comment: Did you check the config file `config/main.php`?

Comment: Yes, I can't reach any of the models there I'm afraid. I get "Trying to get property of non-object" error while trying to use the Yii::$app->user->identity->user_lang;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same problem while ago, and found a solution by adding another component.

[How to load class at every page load in advanced app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42498431/how-to-load-class-at-every-page-load-in-advanced-app)

Add class in config to components part and load it at start by adding to bootstrap.

**config.php**

```
$config = [
    // ..
    'components' => [
        'InitRoutines' => [
            'class' => 'app\commands\InitRoutines', // my custom class
        ],
    ],
];

$config['bootstrap'][] = 'InitRoutines';
```

Then make your class to extend `Component` with `init()` method

**InitRoutines.php**

```
namespace app\commands;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Component;
use app\commands\AppHelper;
use app\commands\Access;

class InitRoutines extends Component
{
    // this method runs at start at every page load
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        Access::checkForMaintenance(); // my custom method
        Yii::$app->language = AppHelper::getUserLanguageCode(); // my custom method
    }
}
```

Comment: That's nice! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can attach to the application event [beforeAction](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-module.html#EVENT_BEFORE_ACTION-detail) or [beforeRequest](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-application.html#EVENT_BEFORE_REQUEST-detail) and do your stuff here. It seems easier to me e.g.:

```
$config = [
    // ..
    'on beforeRequest' => function($event) {
        Yii::$app->language='en-EN';           
    }
];
```